# NSMutableArray alloc init deprecated in iOS9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated

I am using Deploymate tool to check deprecation and iOS version compatibility, some of you might know. It is telling me

```
init
Deprecated in iOS 9.0
```

for code like

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Could not find anything about deprecation. Can someone enligten me. Is this a "bug" in Deploymate or is it really deprecated? Do I need to change something to

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Both lines of code you posted are the same.

Comment: alloc & init calls can't be deprecated, that wouldn't even make sense, it's a bug in the Deploymate tool you're using

Comment: I believe there's a bug in the tool. If it bothers you, try  `[NSMutableArray array]` or `[NSMutableArray arrayWitheArray:@[]]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Deploymate but it seems like it seems like it may prefer you to use `[NSMutableArray new];` instead of `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`.

However you can't use the `new` method if you pass in init options such as `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@"Foo", @"Bar"]];`.

Comment: Or you can do `[@[ @"Foo", @"Bar" ] mutableCopy];`.